# 'BusinessLayer.EmployeeBusinessLayer' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: asp.net-mvc

in a classLiberary named (BusinessLayer)

i have made a class Employee.cs--->

```
public class Employee
    {
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
        public string EmployeeCity { get; set; }
        public string EmployeeGender { get; set; }
        public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    }
```

then added another class EmployeeBusinessLayer.cs

```
class EmployeeBusinessLayer
    {
        public IEnumerable<Employee> Employees
        {
            get
            {
                string ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
                 List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
                {
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sqlGetAllEmployees", con);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    con.Open();
                    SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    while (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        Employee employee = new Employee();
                        employee.DepartmentId = Convert.ToInt16(rdr["DepartmentId"]);
                        employee.EmployeeId = Convert.ToInt16(rdr["EmployeeId"]);
                        employee.EmployeeName = rdr["EmployeeName"].ToString();
                        employee.EmployeeCity = rdr["EmployeeCity"].ToString();
                        employee.EmployeeGender = rdr["EmployeeGender"].ToString();
                        employees.Add(employee);

                    }
                }
                return Employees;
            }


        }
    }
```

and then when i was using it in my project after adding the reference then it is showing "BusinessLayer.EmployeeBusinessLayer' is inaccessible due to its protection level"

```
 public class EmployeesController : Controller
        {

            public ActionResult Index()
            {
   EmployeeBusinessLayer employeeBusinessLayer = new EmployeeBusinessLayer();
              List<Employee> employees =  employeeBusinessLayer.Employees;
                return View(employees);
            }

        }
```

Comment: Make `class EmployeeBusinessLayer` public - `public class EmployeeBusinessLayer`

Answer (score 1):

You need to make EmployeeBusinessLayer accessible to the Controller class.

You can for example make it public:

```
public class EmployeeBusinessLayer {  ...
```